# How to store output of (mpstat) command in a variable in shell script

Tags: command-line, cpu-load

I want to store each output of commands `mpstat` or `mpstat -P ALL`,  like `%usr,%nice,%sys,...` in a variable.

Can you help me to do this,because I want to sum some of them.

Answer (score 1):

Its a tough one but still I am managed to get something for you.

This line will print CPU data in a variable named CPU

```
eval "$(mpstat | awk '{print $3}' | xargs | awk '{print $2"="$3}')"
```

after doing this execute `echo $CPU`

you will get

```
[root@localhost BASH]# echo $CPU
all
[root@localhost BASH]#
```

and for `%usr` you can use `eval "$(mpstat | awk '{print $4}' | xargs | awk '{print "USR="$3}')"`

look at below example

```
[root@localhost BASH]# eval "$(mpstat | awk '{print $4}' | xargs | awk '{print "USR="$3}')"
[root@localhost BASH]# echo $USR
0.11
[root@localhost BASH]#
```

I hope you understand how to do this and you can develop complete code for what you want.

Summary:

```
[root@localhost BASH]# cat  forsome.sh
#!/bin/bash
eval "$(mpstat | awk '{print $3}' | xargs | awk '{print $2"="$3}')"
eval "$(mpstat | awk '{print $4}' | xargs | awk '{print "USR="$3}')"
echo "Number of CPU's :"$CPU
echo "%usr value      :"$USR

[root@localhost BASH]# ./forsome.sh
Number of CPU's :all
%usr value      :0.11
[root@localhost BASH]#
```

Comment: Thanks dear friend How about %nice,%sys,...can I do something like this to store %nice for example in another variable?      nice=$("$(mpstat | awk '{print $4}' | xargs | awk '{print "NICE="$3}')")  and sys=$("$(mpstat | awk '{print $4}' | xargs | awk '{print "SYS="$3}')")

Comment: and show the result of two sys and nice with echo inside the shell like this echo "%nice"$nice  and show result of sys,  echo "%sys"$sys,    is the correct?

Comment: To develop remaining part of the script you should learn awk. So you will understand what need to be done.